# Why are two identical functions not equal?

Tags: javascript

I let function A and function B print the same thing. But why the object constructed by A and the object b constructed by B are not equal?

```js
function A() {
  alert("k")
};

function B() {
  alert("k")
};

let a = new A();
let b = new B();

alert(a == b);
```

Comment: Because `new` creates a new object. Even `let a = new A(); let b = new A();` will return distinct objects.

Comment: == works differently on different types of objects. for functions, I think it's just comparing addresses in memory.